# How we invoke Drupal WebService in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, drupal

I want to make project in iOS. I have web service in drupal How we invoke in objective c. And what is procedure.

Comment: Well, what you tried so far?

Comment: i want to try invoke i m using just using simple synch call

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSUrlConnection` documented at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html